# Delete duplicate alias using keytool

Tags: encryption, weblogic, jaas, keytool

I have a keystore JKS file have 2 entries with same alias. ie.g

```
mykey CN=keysto,DC=test,DC=company,DC=com
mykey CN=enccry,DC=test,DC=comapny,DC=com
```

I need to delete one of the entries. When I run `keytool -delete -alias mykey -keystore test.jks`, it deletes both the aliases.

Answer (score 0):

If the Keytool deletes both the entries with the same alias, you can follow this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292718/java-keystore-duplicate-aliases) to change/rename the duplicate aliases. You can then delete the one you want to delete.